# Scrolling an image inside a imageView in android

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, effects, android-kenburnsview

I am working on an application in which I am having a large image and need to display that image in a imageview of small size . I was thinking to view the whole image by scrolling the image inside the image view automatic.Can it be posible ?

I have tried the following but not getting satisfaction.
[Android how do I zoom and scroll a bitmap which is created on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563614/android-how-do-i-zoom-and-scroll-a-bitmap-which-is-created-on-the-fly)

[Android Autoscroll imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352253/android-autoscroll-imageview)

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

In short Need to develop [KEN BURNS EFFECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect)

I tried https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView  but getting error as follows :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.MathUtils.getRectRatio(MathUtils.java:44)
```

Comment: `not getting satisfaction` is a little vague. Describe precisely your current problem. (read this http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for good advices on how to improve your question)

Comment: I just pushed some code to fix the bug you're experiencing. You can now use v1.0.3.